# Django-rest saving model against a specific user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which has user as a foreign key:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    what_task = models.CharField(max_length=100, )

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.what_task)
```

It's serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    steps = StepSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'


    def create(self, validated_data):
        steps_data = validated_data.pop('steps')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for step_data in steps_data:
            Step.objects.create(task=task, **step_data)
        return task
```

And in my view I have a function that handles `GET` and `POST` request. GET is correct it returns me all the tasks of a specific user-I use `request.user.id` for it.

I am not sure about my POST, how can I save task against a specific user in this case:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):
    """
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Where I must make change, in serializer or in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your models,

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
```

Then, migrate your changes.

Then, In your views,

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Do I also need to add user field in my request JSON? because it gave me ´{"user":["This field is required."]}´ error.

Comment: Updated the answer.